# how to make navbar on top of carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I made a navbar and I have carousel slider, I can't put the navbar on top of it (not fixed) I don't need the navbar to take space

here's an example of what I'm talking about: http://demo.designshopify.com/html_lavie/lavie_resturant/index.html

I tried to change the css to:

```
 .navbar {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:1;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
```

}

but still the navbar not on top..

Answer (score 0):

Simple just add the class

> navbar-static-top

along with the navbar class, 
I think You should read the bootstrap docs http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the navbar to take up space, and want it to overlay the content, use the fixed navbar..

`navbar-fixed-top`

http://www.codeply.com/go/xp2fY6sVHP